# Sorting strings in go lang

Tags: go

How do I sort strings like 4.3.4, 4.3.30 in golang. There is a method named "sort" in golang? The issue is that with this method 4.3.30 prints before 4.3.4. I want 4.3.30 to print after 4.3.4. What is the logic to do this sorting? 
Note- I just need a logic weather it will be in go or java.
Thanks in advance. 
for you reference, "sort" program in go:

```
package main

import "sort"
import "fmt"

type ByLength []string

func (s ByLength) Len() int {
    return len(s)
}
func (s ByLength) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}
func (s ByLength) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return (s[i]) < (s[j])
}
func main() {
    abc := []string{"1.5.8", "5.8.4", "4.3.30"}
    sort.Sort(ByLength(abc))
    fmt.Println(abc)
}
```

Comment: Read the docs for the [sort](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) package.

Comment: If you’re comparing semver strings, use one of the many packages already created for handling versions.

Comment: That this question was voted down so much (I found it at -7) is an example of why Stack Overflow is considered hostile. So the asker didn't know something? That's the whole point of asking a question! I'm disappointed in this community.

Answer (score 2):

Strings without special handling are sorted [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

This means that "30" in string terms is smaller than "4" because the character "3" is lexicographically smaller than the character "4".

If you want to sort these based on integer values within the string, you need to make your own sorter.

So in your comparator function `func (s ByLength) Less(i, j int) bool`, you can do something along the lines of:

- split strings by `.`
- convert each string part into an integer
- iterate over both integer slices (at the same time)
- compare the numbers

This of course only works for the `.` separated strings, you would have to adapt this for other separators.
You also have to worry about non-integer parts and strings with different number of parts (eg: `4.3` vs `4.3.5`)

Comment: yes Marc thank you so much. but actually i am just learning go right now. So if you could help me in making the logic for the splitting and comparing,  i would be very grateful to u .  thank you in advance